# How to auto refresh list after delete item with button click

Tags: javascript, angular

I have my backend with a route to delete an article using its id, now in Angular I have this list of articles and each row has a button when I click on it I want to delete this article from the database, good I have accomplished this BUT then thing is the list of articles is not auto-refreshing so the deleted article is still there

I have the ArticleService file with 2 methods: 1 for get all the articles (this is called when the app is launched) and the delete article one, I want that after I successfully delete the article the list of articles shows no more that article without me having to manually refresh the page

this is my ArticleService file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Article } from '../models/article';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {
  private url: string;
  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) {
    this.url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';
  }

  getArticles(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.get(this.url + 'get-articles', {headers:headers});
  }
  deteleArticle(id:any){
    console.log('Voy a borrar el articulo con id ' + id);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.delete(this.url + 'delete-article/' + id, {headers:headers});
  }
}
```

the Article component html:

```html
<div class="actions-container" id="deletebtn">
        <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="deleteArticle(data._id)">
            <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
```

the ArticlesListComponent.html

```html
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let article of data_array">
        <app-article [data]='article'></app-article>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

ArticleComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { ArticleService } from '../shared/article.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article',
  templateUrl: './article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article.component.css']
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  constructor(
    private datePipe: DatePipe,
    private _articleService: ArticleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public deleteArticle(id):void{
    this._articleService.deteleArticle(id).subscribe(response=>{
      console.log(response);
    },error=>{
      if(<any>error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and the ArticlesListComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticleService } from '../shared/article.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-articles-list',
  templateUrl: './articles-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articles-list.component.css'],
  providers:[ArticleService]
})
export class ArticlesListComponent implements OnInit {

  public data_array = [];
  constructor(private articleService: ArticleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Article-List component ready.');
    this.getAllPost();
  }

  getAllPost(){
    this.articleService.getArticles().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.data_array = result['articles'];
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

How can I do to refresh the list or after delete article

Comment: Once you delete the article, update your `this.data_array`. I'am not really sure what is response of `deteleArticle` method or other alternative would be to again call the service `getArticles()` which will retrieve your updated data and use output emitter to send it back to `mat-list-item`.

Answer (score 0):

In your article component you can add an event and trigger in the delete method when the call to delete the item is complete, then suscribe to that event in the articleListComponent. When the method in the articleListComponent suscribed to the event runs, identified the element that was deleted from the array and delete it from there too.
You can return in the event, the id of the item deleted and search it in the array. Remember that your view isn't going to be refreshed for the reference to the array when you delete the item from the array. You will have to make a new array with the remaining items.

You can do that like this

```
  this.data_array  = [...this.data_array];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call again this Method :

> getAllPost()

Because you have a share service  the succes of **deleteArticle()** method you can call **getAllPost()** method it will refresh your list.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you have to  make the output EventEmitter in ArticleComponent.ts

```
 @Output() public handleDelete: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Emit this event with deleted element id when record is successfully deleted

```
public deleteArticle(id):void{
    this._articleService.deteleArticle(id).subscribe(response=>{
    this.handleDelete.emit(id);  
      console.log(response);
    },error=>{
      if(<any>error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

In  ArticlesListComponent.html add (handleDelete)="deleteHandle($event)"

```
 <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let article of data_array">
            <app-article [data]='article' (handleDelete)="deleteHandle($event)"></app-article>
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
```

In ArticleComponent.ts add deleteHandle method in that we can either remove the deleted element from the data_array to  prevent another server call or you can call getAllPost() which refresh the list

```
deleteHandle(id)
{
    var index = data_array.indexOf(e => e._id ==id);

    if (index > -1) {
       data_array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

or

```
deleteHandle(id)
{
   this.getAllPost()
}
```

hope  this will  help you.

Comment: I did this and is removing from DB but is not refreshing the list i have to reload it manually